# Using alias in subquery's WHERE clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In postgresql, I have a users table with `name` and `meta_data` columns. `Meta_data` column is jsonb, I store data like:

```
"{"likes": [{"id": "1", "name": "aaa"}, {"id": "2", "name": "bbb"}, {"id": "3", "name": "ccc"}]}"
```

For each like, I'd like to select the number of users that have the same like.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id' AS like_id,
(SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.meta_data->'likes'->>'id' = like_id ) AS count_users
FROM users
```

Furthermore I have a `clickouts` table with `user_id` column. I need the number of clickouts made by the users who has that specific like_id.

```
COUNT(clickouts.id) FILTER ( 
    WHERE clickouts.user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE users.meta_data->'likes'->>'id' = like_id)
)
```

These queries do not work. The error message is:

> column "like_id" does not exist.

Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: `..,COUNT(jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id') AS..` You need to repeat the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use the same logic in the where like this:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id' AS like_id,
(SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.meta_data->'likes'->>'id' = jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id' ) AS count_users
FROM users
```

But it seems if there are more then 1 row for each like_id, you will have a lot of duplicates, so you should use group by.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id' AS like_id,
count(jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id') AS count_users
FROM users
GROUP BY jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id'
```

EDIT:

If you want to use the alias in the inner query, try something like this:

```
SELECT t.like_id,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users.meta_data->'likes'->>'id' = t.like_id ) AS count_users FROM (
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(users.meta_data->'likes')->>'id' AS like_id,
FROM users) t
```

Comment: Thank you, the second solution works. But I need 'like_id' in subqueries. I updated the question. If I try your first solution, I got this error: argument of WHERE must not return a set.

Comment: @user3782471 If you wrap you query with another select, you will be able to use this alias. I've edited my question.. take the query and adjust it how ever you want.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you.